# Linking GA4 to BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery, google-analytics-4

I have linked Google Analytics 4 (GA4) to BigQuery for data extraction.

Currently BigQuery extracts data for each separate day from google analytics 4.
Instead, i'd like it to be continuous flow of data (meaning one table with time-series data, rather than each day having an individual separate table).

How could I make this change?

Many thanks,

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1qbkD.png)

.

Answer (score 1):

I remembered that it is designed this way.

If you want to query multiple days in multiple table.

Here is the sample sql

```
select
    *
from
    -- change this to your google analytics 4 export location in bigquery
    `ga4bigquery.analytics_(change_to_yours).events_*`
where
    _table_suffix between '20230101' and '20230327'
```

The reference from the [website](https://www.ga4bigquery.com/tutorial-how-to-query-multiple-analytics-events-tables-with-table-suffix-ga4/).

Comment: Another resource here: https://developers.google.com/analytics/bigquery/basic-queries

Answer (score 0):

That's the way the export "partitions" the data. It will reduce cost as you only pay for the "partitions" you query against.